# How to allow empty strings in Django serializer's datetime fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I attached my serializer code.

I'm working with Django Rest Framework. Normally you can setup a serializer in less than 5 lines of code but this is not the case. The problem is that the FE sends date_start or date_end as empty string instead as null when the user did not set them inside the form.

In the current code, to allow the FE to pass date_start and date_end as an empty string, I set on them a temporary not empty value, so that the validation can work and, before to save the data to the DB, I revert this special value to None. Anything works... but...

I know that it is an ugly solution, is there a better way to pass date_time as "" instead as null ?

I have to use Django 1.10

```python
class RulesSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    __None__ = "__None__"
    nullable_fields = ( 'date_end', 'rules', 'date_start', 'price_base')

    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    country_code = serializers.CharField()
    operator_name = serializers.CharField()
    operator_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    calculation_base = serializers.CharField()
    price_base = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    rules = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    value_format = serializers.CharField()
    value = serializers.FloatField()
    date_start = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    date_end = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    def to_rapresentation(self, instance):
        return super(RulesSerializer,self).to_rapresentation(instance)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):

        for field in self.nullable_fields:
            if field in data:
                data[field] = data[field] or self.__None__
        return super(RulesSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        logger.info("now executes the update for the not allowed blank fields")
        for field in self.nullable_fields:
            if field not in validated_data:
                continue
            if validated_data[field] == self.__None__:
                validated_data[field] = None

        for field in validated_data.keys():
            setattr(instance, field, validated_data[field])

        instance.save()
        return instance

    def create(self, validated_data): 
        for field in self.nullable_fields:
            if field not in validated_data:
                continue
            if validated_data[field] == self.__None__:
                validated_data[field] = None
        new_rule = Rules()
        for field in validated_data:
            setattr(new_rule, field, validated_data[field])

        new_rule.save()
        return new_rule 

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Rules
        read_only_fields = list('id')
```

Comment: Did you try setting "allow_none" property to True?

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#allow_null

Comment: allow_none or allow_null ? @adkl